# My List is being sorted by the alphabetical order after sorting by date while I'm adding the 4-5 items in my List

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-listview, sortedlist, sortedmap

My List is being sorted by the alphabetical order after sorting by date while I am adding extra  4-5 items  in my List with different names. I want to sort my List by date and time only.

here I have shared my code please help me to do so.
thanks in advance.

```
// Filters All patient to keep only single latest record of each patient id
private List<PatientData> filterPatients(List<PatientData> allPatientData) throws ParseException {

    HashMap<String ,Pair<PatientData,Date>> filtered = new HashMap<>();
    SimpleDateFormat inSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    for(PatientData p : allPatientData){
        if(filtered.containsKey(p.getPatientId())){
            Pair<PatientData,Date> _p = filtered.get(p.getPatientId());
            Date d1 = _p.second;
            Date d2 = inSdf.parse(p.getScanDate());
            if(d2.after(d1)){
                filtered.put(p.getPatientId(), new Pair<>(p, d2));
            }
        }else{
            if(p.getScanDate() != null)
                filtered.put(p.getPatientId(), new Pair<>(p, inSdf.parse(p.getScanDate())));
        }
    }


    List<Pair<PatientData,Date>> filteredPairs = new ArrayList<>(filtered.values());
    Collections.sort(filteredPairs,new Comparator<Pair<PatientData, Date>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<PatientData, Date> t1, Pair<PatientData, Date> t2) {
            if(t1.second.after(t2.second)){
                return -1;
            }else if (t1.second.before(t2.second)){
                return 1;
            }
            else
                return t1.first.getPatientId().compareTo(t2.first.getPatientId());
        }
    });
    List<PatientData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(filteredPairs.size());



    for(Pair<PatientData,Date> p : filteredPairs){
        filteredList.add(p.first);
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: To avoid sorting by patient ID, instead of `return t1.first.getPatientId().compareTo(t2.first.getPatientId());` use `return 0;`?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They are not only long outdated, the latter is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: can you please send me the implementation of code because i m new in android so its difficult to understand the how to implement.

Comment: Sorry, it’s hard for me to provide working code. I cannot get your code to work here because it depends on classes and methods that I don’t have. And I’m not sure I have understood your problem. A (reduced) example of desired result and observed result would help so we can see exactly how they differ. Which code works for you also depends on your API level, which I din’t know.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

First, in your `PatientData` class don’t use a string for scan date. Use a date-time type and prefer the modern `Instant` over the old-fashioned `Date`. As a convenience you may have a constructor and/or a setter that accepts a string and parses it. For example:

```
public class PatientData {

    private String patientId;
    private Instant scanDate;

    public PatientData(String patientId, String scanDateString) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
        setScanDate(scanDateString);
    }

    public void setScanDate(String scanDateString) {
        scanDate = Instant.parse(scanDateString);
    }

    // getters, etc.
}
```

Now you have no need for building pairs, you can just use the `PatientData` class alone. To sort a list of `PatientData`:

```
    Collections.sort(filteredList, new Comparator<PatientData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PatientData pd1, PatientData pd2) {
            return pd1.getScanDate().compareTo(pd2.getScanDate());
        }
    });
```

Or if you API level is high enough (corresponding to Java 8):

```
    Collections.sort(filteredList, Comparator.comparing(PatientData::getScanDate));
```

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.